# Mold on Canned Cherry pie filling

Tags: food-safety, pie, mold

I have cherry pie filling (from a can) which grew some mold. Can I remove the mold and eat the rest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not eat this.  Various molds can impact food beyond what you can see. There are some instances where mold can be removed, for example the white mold that sometimes forms on the surface of a ferment.  However, in this case, I would err on the side of caution, discard, and open a new can.